# Resizing html tag background image to scale with screen using css

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that displays full width on the screen in the html css style sheet:

```
html {
    background-image: url('../images/htmlbackground.png') ;
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The body width is set to 70%. The CSS code for the body is:

```
body {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto 2em;
    font: 100% Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #000000
}
```

In the header section of the body is full width of the body and overlays the background image. The main body of the document contains two columns: one containing text and one containing a slideshow.

The problem I am having is that if I zoom 'in' in the browser window, the column 1 and column 2 sections float into the background image and doesn't look well at all. Is it possible to resize the html background image as the user scrolls so the body and html image stay in relative position to each other? Any other suggestions on how to do accomplish the desired results? The posts I have seen seem to deal with images in  tags not the  tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `background-size` property
Stretch the background image to completely cover the content area:

```
html {
    background-image: url('../images/htmlbackground.png') ;
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, CSS Tricks has a good tutorial of [a variety of ways to scale a background image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). If you want a purely CSS way, use this:

```
html {
  background: url('../images/htmlbackground.png') center center no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Make sure you use browser prefixes to make sure it works across all platforms.